# Typeahead to show multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap tyepahead that gets live data from my database. Rather than just returning one word from the database (the person's username), I want to be able to return multiple values (an image link and some other information from the database).

HTML and jQuery/Ajax:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type something...">

<script>
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/script.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: 'query=' + query,
                success: function(data) {
                    process(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    include_once("connect_info.php");

    $cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Couldn't connect to the server. Please try again.");

    $return = array();

    if(isset($_POST['query'])){
        $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username LIKE concat("%", ?, "%")');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['query']);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $return[] = $row['user_id'];
        }
    }

    $json = json_encode($return);
    print_r($json);

?>
```

How would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself, it was a lot easier than I thought it would be.

Here's my new code:

HTML and jQuery/Ajax:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type something...">

<script>
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/script.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: 'query=' + query,
                success: function(data) {
                    process(data);
                }
            });
        },
        highlighter: function(data) {
            var parts = data.split(','),
            html = '<img src="pictures/' + parts[0] + '.jpg" />';
            html += '<div class="info">' + parts[1] + '</div>';
            return html;
        },
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    include_once("connect_info.php");

    $cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Couldn't connect to the server. Please try again.");

    $return = array();

    if(isset($_POST['query'])){
        $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT user_id, username FROM users WHERE username LIKE concat("%", ?, "%")');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['query']);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $return[] = $row['user_id'] . ',' . $row['username'];
        }
    }

    $json = json_encode($return);
    print_r($json);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return array of Json objects. like 
[ {user_name:"XYZ", image_link:"http://www.mysite.com/my_image}.... ]
I do it this way in python, I am sure you can do the same in PHP.

Please take a look at the last example [ best picture winner ] on the typeahead examples page.
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/